# How to call click event function of menustrip item C#?

Tags: c#, click, menustrip

I want to call the click function of MenuStrip in C# associated with the item of MenuStrip whose index i can provide 
e.g i want to call

```
menuStrip1.Items[0]
```

click function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `PerformClick()`, i.e. `menuStrip1.Items[0].PerformClick();`

Comment: Well i have come to know that i have to go through items in menustrip like i have two items 'Main' and 'About Me' and each have 3 sub items.
The actual thing i wanted to do was to perform the click of say 2nd option in Main category. So can you help me on that ...